# Win 10 boot failure: A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed, error code 0xc000000e

Tags: windows-10, boot

I got a new SSD for my windows 10 home desktop computer recently. I used Macrium to clone the old SSD to the new one.  I put the old SSD away and have been using the new SSD for a few days without issue.  Today I re-connected the old SSD, using a PCIe adapter, with the new SSD still in the NVMe port and formatted it prior to selling it off.  Turned off the computer, removed the formatted old SSD, and now the system doesn't boot.  Just blue screen with: A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed error code 0xc000000e

Here's what I've tried, and the result:

[image: Startup repair fails]

[image]

Here's a list of hopefully relevant data from diskpart:

[image]

I also use the rEFInd boot manager with a dual boot to Linux.  After lockdown I got a linux dev box for work so I haven't been in there for a year.  Happy to let that all go if it makes fixing the rest easier.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: It probably got stuck because the same License was on both SSDs  .

Comment: I see.  Well, if so, then the error message sent me on quite a wild goose chase!

Then again, if that was the problem I would've expected the error message some time ago, as I've been running the system from the new SSD for a couple of days.

Any idea how to verify this hypothesis and/or fix it?  I obviously have a valid license key :)

Comment: I think it was because both licenses were active in the same machine at the same time. Earlier the new SSD was on its own. I did assume your license was valid.

Comment: I did some googling in this direction and it seems changing a drive isn't enough to trigger re-activation.  In any event, you won't be prevented from booting when this *is* required, but prompted to re-activate once you do enter windows (e.g. after changing out your motherboard).

Comment: licencing would not care about it being on two volumes. The system should still boot. What you need to do is to copy the full windows partition from the original to a file via macrium, format the ssd (using a caddy as you need one) then restore the partition to the ssd but restore to the whole disk. assuming you have also got a copy of windows 10 on usb - once the partition is restored to the ssd boot off the usb then run startup repair to sort out boot. You won't have the two extra partitions but windows doesn't need them to work, and putting them back is a lot more effort.

Comment: > "What you need to do is to copy the full windows partition from the original to a file via macrium, format the ssd (using a caddy as you need one) then restore the partition to the ssd but restore to the whole disk."  

This is what I did.  It worked well.  The problems occurred after I inserted the old drive ,that I cloned, and formatted it. While getting ready to format I remember booting into the wrong OS (menu showed two identical entries and I picked the wrong one).  That worked fine, but I then had to reboot into the right one to actually format the right drive.